# Is "soaring during" ever correct?

Tags: prepositions

Not-so-long ago, I wrote something like "The price of gasoline has been soaring **in** the past few decades" and an American speaker corrected it to "**during**". I understand that a few decades seems like a long time, but as "soaring" implies, it is quite small when compared to the time scale petrol has been around (as far as I know it's been used in cars for a century), so it does not make sense to me.

I was wondering, **is "soaring during" ever correct use**, since it seems like the verb "to soar" always implies a (relatively) **sudden** increase rather than a long and steady one, so "soaring during" strikes me as odd. Since I'm not a native, I would like your opinion on the subject.

I know that there are several "in v.s. during" debates to be seen on the internet, but I am interested in this particular example.

Comment: Am not sure, but it seems it was your use of the present perfect that led to the correction. _The price of gasoline soared in the past few decades_ wouldn't have had that effect, imo. Not a native either, so...

Comment: @MvLog I see, this makes sense indeed

Comment: Aside: a few decades *is* quite a long time in relation to a century. 30 - 40% of that?

Comment: I find the use of *during* to be awkward, and I'd prefer *in*, but neither is ungrammatical.